# Name of this somewhat sci-fi but also fantasy movie based on people on bikes with walls coming out behind them?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, action

There was this one movie I watched ages ago and here are the points of interest:

## Necessary points of detail not related to any plot:

- It was in colour
- It was in English
- The characters I believe were mostly caucasian
- It was based in a dark world
- I saw it early this decade (2010-2015 but I am sure it was around 2012-2013 when I last saw it)
  I believe it originated from country USA
- Setting is as mentioned before but in some unknown universe.
- There were different groups of these bike people namely: Red, Blue, I think Green and Yellow and Red was an enemy.

## The plot:

- There was a man (the protagonist) who was either kidnapped and pulled down into this dark insanely wild world.
- There were multiple people dragged into this place.
- They were in big bubbles where they faced off an opponent, if you lost it was certain death.
- They throw coloured discs at you, you either dodge them and live, or they hit you and die.
- This man threw himself to the ground multiple times avoiding this enemy disc.
- I think he found his own disc and decided to kill the enemy opponent.
- He said something about:

> "I am not a programme"

- I can't remember what exactly happened immediately after that, but this is another scene I remember:

## The arena:

- He was put onto a bike, one that as coloured and had some kind of wall neing produced coming from the back wheel. If a bike hit this, the bike was done for.
- I am sure that the new man cut a lot of people off , I think that he was also knocked off his bike
- Now I remember that the bike was actually a stick that he was given, thown and it comes out as a bike...or any vehicle really...I don't know.
- This woman from the same colour arrived to save him from his remaining enemy...someone who would actually try to kill him.
- She came in a buggy, he got in and they took off with the enemy in pursuit.
- They came across a wide gap with a slight ramp, she sped up, while the man said they weren't going to make it
- They jumped, after a bit, they landed on the otherside and she said:

  > "Made it."

## Other scenes I remember:

- I can't remember much from other scenes, but I do remember that the man was from the (I think) blue side, the enemy was red (all enemy) and they had to fight against the red.

## The battles:

- From what I remember, the blue and yellow sides team up, the green I think stays neutral.
- There was an invasion of blue against red and they snuck past or killed red guards stealthily.
- I remember the woman backflipping and being very agile in the air while invading red HQ
- An after battle is when they are in the bubbles again fighting the red at close quarters, the woman is on the ground with some red enemy while the red is continuously throusting his red disc into her arm.
- The result of the disc thrusts is a blue crystal like wound going brittle and coming off her arm.
- The protagonist saves her from this by killing the man in some unknown way I can't remember.

## End of plot explanation.

**Thanks guys, your help is very appreciated. I really want to see this movie again as it was a really good movie. Thank-you again**

Comment: I commend your detail, and note with mild amusement that from only the title and none of the details it could only be either *Tron* or *Tron: Legacy*.

Comment: I was going to propose Tron Legacy, but then the OP said `it was a really good movie` ... which rules Tron Legacy right out!  ;-)

Comment: I knew it was Tron the moment I read `They throw coloured discs at you, you either dodge them and live, or they hit you and die.`

Comment: This question reminds me of the somewhat banal description someone gave of a movie asking for a title and it turns out to be "Star Wars".

Comment: @Michael: "...and so like there's this kid and he's got a sword and a robot and some old guy comes along and then another younger guy but older shows up with this space ship and a long-haired gorilla that grunts a lot and the gold robot says 'Oh, dear!' a lot and the old guy fights the guy in the black mask and he dies but not really and the little cute robot squeaks and beeps and the girl was like a babe and then the world blows up and then the big spaceship blows up and...does anyone know the girl's name?". You mean *that* description? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis It was a bit more subtle I think, like "There's this kid with a robot that only he seems to understand.  He lived in a dry place but I remember him saying something about how it was a farm because his uncle wanted him to do chores, but he wants to leave for a big city.  Anyway, he meets this old hippie who shows him a blue sword because I think he had been in a war but had gone into hiding for some reason, and he takes him to this big city and somehow they wind up going somewhere else but their transportation is old and keeps malfunctioning.

Comment: @BobJarvis: almost, but the actual question was a description of Episode I…

Comment: @Michael [Movie about a boy, two men, a robot and a war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/154621/31221)

Comment: "[..] bikes with walls coming out behind them" - That's Tron. It was exceptionally amusing to see such a detailed question for a movie that you can more or less guess from the title alone. Kudos for the OP for the effort on polishing his question to this level.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Based on the timeframe given and the "**bikes with walls coming off the back wheel**" bit, this is almost certainly [Tron: Legacy](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1104001/?ref_=ttmi_tt) (2010.)

Here's one of the bikes from Legacy, tell me if I'm right:
[image]

Incidentally, in case you're curious, this movie is a sequel to 1982's *Tron.*

Comment: There are also Identity Discs and a Disc Arena in the film too! :)

Comment: Original Tron movie also had them.

Comment: +1 for the "sequel to" note - in my opinion, the original is excellent, better even than 2. (although the soundtrack isn't quite as good)

Comment: There were also Disney series based on the same universe

Comment: And a Kingdom Hearts level

Comment: @DeepDeadpool Two, even

Comment: And a really cool (and free!) game called *Armagetron*.

Comment: Used up a lot of quarters playing the Tron arcade game.

Comment: And we had our own variety of the Identity Disks game using frisbees when I was a kid, too.